# android : hide snackbar below soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-snackbar, soft-keyboard

i am showing the snackbar on some activities. Now if an edittext is clicked which triggers sof keyboard to pop up , the snackbar is puched to above the keyboard. I want the keyboard to be above the snackbar as in layered and that snackbar is not visible as long as keyboard is visible.
How can this be achieved

Comment: did you check this [Handling Input Method Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can simply do in the manifest in your activity add this attribute:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

That's it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainContent, error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E32C29"));
// Changing action button text color
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTypeface(tf);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(AppController.getCurrentContext(), R.color.white));
textView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
} else {
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
snackbar.show();
```